# revolution slider video size changes to original after 10 seconds

Tags: jquery, wordpress, html5-video, revolution-slider

I have a webpage where revolution slider is used with videos in a Div, however when Loading that page all videos render with small size but after 10 seconds it gains original dimensions. Also if I use alert(); in callback function, it shows all videos with original dimensions in no time.

div with id divVideoSection is where slider is used.

```
  jQuery("#TakeMeToVids").click(function () {
        jQuery('#divPreLoadBody').hide();
        jQuery('#divVideoSection').show('fast', function () {
            window.alert();
        });

    });
```

Comment: Though your question includes some information e.g. you are checking dom elements for loading, But not show how you have placed your revslider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending 2 days, I just added below lines to refresh the Dom as Alert(); was also doing the same thing. And that solved the Issue.

```
 jQuery(window).trigger('resize');
```

Comment: Your video must be getting size after getting metadata, When you add Alert execution stops and you are getting more time. Add `loadedmetadata` in your code and display video after that.